# Ember.js: difference between {{#collection}} and {{#each}}?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In Ember.js, what's the difference between using `{{#collection}}` and `{{#each}}`? In which cases would you use which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hum, well... quite a good question... as you can see here : [#729](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/729), it seems that the `{{collection}}` helper is going to be deprecated in favor of using always `{{#each}}`. But at this time, all features available in `{{#collection}}` are not in `{{#each}}`.

So, I would recommend you to use `{{#each}}` when it works for you, and only use `{{collection}}` when absolutely needed. <strike>(when you need to define itemViewClass for example).</strike>

Update: since  1.0.0-pre.2, the itemViewClass attribute to the each helper. The only remaining thing the `collection` helper has over the `each` one, is you can explicitely define the collection class to use if you have extended Ember.CollectionView.